# How to plot a vertical thermal plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

How to plot this kind of thermal plot in Python? I tried to search for any sample plot like this but didn't find one.

This image I got from the internet. I want to plot something same like this:
[image: This image I got from the internet. I want to plot something same like this]

Comment: Dear All,
I found this plot code in MATLAB. But I want to re-write the coding by using any library which is working in python. 

Link-: https://github.com/nasa/LH2Sim/tree/master/sim

Here, check the "drawTank" matlab file. But still I could not run that file as well. Bit difficult to identify the issue as I am bit new to programming.

Answer (score 0):

## FROM

[image]

## TO

[image]

---

To represent this type of data the canonical solution is, of course, a heat map. Here it is the code to produce both the figures at the top of this post.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.linspace(0, 5, 501)
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 201)[:, None]


T = 50 + (30-6*t)*(4*x*(1-x)) + 4*t

fig, ax = plt.subplots(layout='constrained')
hm = ax.imshow(T, cmap='plasma',
               aspect='auto', origin='lower', extent=(0, 5, 0, 1))
fig.colorbar(hm)

def heat_lines(x, t, T, n):
    from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable
    from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

    lx, lt = T.shape
    ones = np.ones(lx)
    norm = plt.Normalize(np.min(T), np.max(T))
    plasma = plt.cm.plasma
    
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(1+1.2*n, 9), layout='constrained')
    ax.set_xlim((-0.6, n-0.4))
    ax.set_ylim((x[0], x[-1]))
    ax.set_xticks(range(n))
    ax.tick_params(right=False,top=False, bottom=False)
    ax.spines["top"].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines["right"].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines["bottom"].set_visible(False)
    ax.grid(axis='y')
    fig.colorbar(ScalarMappable(cmap=plasma, norm=norm))

    dt = round(lt/(n-1))
    for pos, ix in enumerate(range(0, len(t)+dt//2, dt)):
        points = np.array([ones*pos, x[:,0]]).T.reshape(-1,1,2)    
        segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1], points[1:]], axis=1)
        lc = LineCollection(segments, linewidth=72, ec=None,
                            color=plasma(norm(T[:,ix])))
        lc.set_array(T[:,ix])
        ax.add_collection(lc)

heat_lines(x, t, T, 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact solution I was looking for.

```
# Define the new tick labels for the y-axis
new_yticklabels = ['L1', 'L2', 'L3', 'L4', 'L5', 'L6', 'L7', 'L8', 'L9', 'L10', 'L11', 'L12', 'L13', 'L14', 'L15', 'L16', 'L17', 'L18', 'L19', 'L20']

# Reorder the columns to match the control volumes
ddf = ddf[['T1', 'T2', 'T3', 'T4', 'T5', 'T6', 'T7', 'T8', 'T9', 'T10', 'T11', 'T12', 'T13', 'T14', 'T15', 'T16', 'T17', 'T18', 'T19', 'T20']]

# Create a numpy array from the dataframe
data = np.array(ddf)

# Swap the dimensions of the data array
data = data.T

# Set the figure size
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=len(ddf.index), figsize=(16, 8))
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.4)

# Loop over each time point and plot the heatmap in a subplot
for i, ax in enumerate(axs.flat):
    heatmap = ax.pcolor(data[:, i:i+1], cmap='coolwarm', edgecolor='gray', linewidth=0.5)
    # ax.set_title(ddf.index[i], fontsize=14)
    ax.set_xticks([])

    if i == 0:
        ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0.5, len(ddf.columns), 1))
        ax.set_yticklabels(new_yticklabels, fontsize=12, rotation=0)
    else:
        ax.set_yticks([])

    # Set the x-axis label to the time in seconds
    ax.set_xlabel(f'{ddf.index[i]} (s)', fontsize=12)

    # Add colorbar to the last subplot
    if i == len(ddf.index) - 1:
        cbar = fig.colorbar(heatmap, ax=ax, shrink=0.5)
        cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=12)

# Add a common title for the figure
fig.suptitle('Temperature Variation with Tank Height', fontsize=16, y=0.95)
# Add a common x label and y label
fig.text(0.5, 0.05, 'Time (s)', ha='center', fontsize=14)
fig.text(0.05, 0.5, 'Tank height', va='center', rotation='vertical', fontsize=14)
# fig.tight_layout()
fig.savefig('heatmap1.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.5, format='png')
plt.show()
plt.close()
```